# I am trying to implement the mapbox_gl api in Flutter. How can I set mapbox access token as a system variable or environment variable

Tags: flutter, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android

When I run the code below I'm getting errors in that nature
**A problem occurred evaluating project ':mapbox_gl'.

> SDK Registry token is null. See README.md for more information.**

I believe setting mapbox access token as global or environment variable could solve the problem. If anyone can assist with respect to which files I need to create to store the key and how do I access the token[enter image description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cR3uUTbzrxeRhCqP9XUWpeWFgcSS775Z/view?usp=sharing)

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: loadConfigFile(),
        builder: (BuildContext buildContext,
            AsyncSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return MapboxMap(
                accessToken: snapshot.data['mapbox_api_token'],
                initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: LatLng(-17.8075325, 30.9532117)));
          }
          else {

            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )

          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

An image illustrating the actual error if this can help make this question clear

Comment: Where is the `MapboxMap` object coming from? (i.e package)

Comment: Can you provide more details on the `loadConfigFile()` function?

Comment: The MapboxMap is coming from an imported package(mapbox_gl).                                        import 'package:mapbox_gl/mapbox_gl.dart';

Comment: The loadConfigFile is in separate file and looks like this:                                          
                                                                                                                                   
  import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

const _CONFIG_FILE_PATH = 'assets/config.json';

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> loadConfigFile() async{

  String json = await rootBundle.loadString(_CONFIG_FILE_PATH);
  return jsonDecode(json) as Map <String, dynamic>;

Comment: Does the error come up when you try to build the application, or when the screen is loaded?

Comment: It comes before the screen loads. The error occurs during the build

Answer (score 1):

It says in package README. You need to create a private token and add it to `gradle.properties`.

Package: https://github.com/flutter-mapbox-gl/maps

MapBox instructions: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/